# Integrate R script into SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, r, t-sql, sql-server-2016

So I have the following integrated R code which I use to be able to match stuff via regex without too much complication (what I want to do eventually is more complex than this example so regex is pretty much required, this is just the first step):

```sql
DECLARE @in_adcn nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @out_ou nvarchar(500)
SET @in_adcn = N'CN=Surname\, Firstname (asdf),OU=999,OU=Department2,OU=Fixed,OU=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed'
SET @out_ou = N''

-- Extract department name from AD OU string
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R',
    @script = N'
        pat = "^.+OU=([^,]+),OU=Fixed,OU=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed$";
        m <- gsub(pat, "\\1", regmatches(in_adcn1, gregexpr(pat, in_adcn1))[[1]]);
        out_ou1 <- m;',
    @params = N'@in_adcn1 varchar(500), @out_ou1 varchar(500) output',
    @in_adcn1 = @in_adcn,
    @out_ou1 = @out_ou OUTPUT
WITH RESULT SETS NONE;
SELECT @out_ou;
GO
```

This works fine, it returns exactly what I want from the AD distinguishedName string (in this case: "Department2").

Now I want that output string inside this SELECT query (the input string for the R script is `acad.ADCn`):

```sql
SELECT
    acad.ADCn,
    (
        --<here should be the code that returns the string from the R script above>
    ) AS Departmentname,
    acad.NBAccountName,
    acb.eMail
FROM
    MyDB.dbo.AccountTable AS acad
LEFT JOIN
    MyDB.dbo.AddressTable AS acb
    ON
        acad.[ObjectID]
        = acb.[ObjectID]
```

So far I haven't managed to get this right yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you would like is to have a scalar User Defined Function calling the `sp_execute_external_script` where you passed in the `acad.ADcn` to the function. However since you cannot call a UDF from inside a function you are out of luck. However, in this case - why do you want to use R for regex, couldn't you create a SQLCLR procedure/function that did this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider inputting the entire `SELECT` query as an `@input_data_1` param (following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-working-with-inputs-and-outputs) example). Then, run your regex operation to a new saved dataframe column, *DepartmentName*. Finally, output the entire four column resultset.

```sql
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'R'
    , @script = N' df <- InputDataSet;
                   pat = "^.+OU=([^,]+),OU=Fixed,OU=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed,DC=Fixed$";
                   df$DepartmentName <- gsub(pat, "\\1", regmatches(df$ADCn, gregexpr(pat, df$ADCn))[[1]]);
                   OutputDataSet <- df[c("ADCn", "DepartmentName", "NBAccountName", "eMail")];'
    , @input_data_1 = N' SELECT acad.ADCn, acad.NBAccountName, acb.eMail
                         FROM MyDB.dbo.AccountTable AS acad
                         LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.AddressTable AS acb
                            ON acad.[ObjectID] = acb.[ObjectID];'
    WITH RESULT SETS (( [ADCn] varchar(255), [DepartmentName] varchar(255), [NBAccountName] varchar(255), [eMail] varchar(255) ));
```

*Of course without data, above is untested. Please adjust to fit needs especially with input of ADCn.*

Comment: Almost perfect! Just 2 issues left: somehow this returns the same departmentname for every ADCn (there should be a lot of different ones). The first ADCn which contains "Department9" seems to be the one that is used again and again, because in the end they're all in "Department9" (which isn't true). And the second problem: this generates a "textual table" in the message output. Shouldn't this return a "real" table, because that's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that due to the `[1]` in this line of code: `df$DepartmentName <- gsub(pat, "\\1", regmatches(df$ADCn, gregexpr(pat, df$ADCn))[[1]]);`? What do you mean with "real table"? When I run similar code I get a resultset back with columns etc.

Comment: Yes, thanks. And nevermind about the table issue, I just had a different display active. It works as expected now. Thanks all.